# Bootstrap columns float issue. DIVS need to be same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have dynamically generated content formed into 3 bootstrap columns like this...

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="article">
  content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when columns have different content, the different heights ruin the layout.

How can I force a clear row to be started after every 3 items to avoid this?

So basically...

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can I force a clear row to be started after every 3 items to avoid
>   this

Add a class and try `.your-class:nth-child(3n) {clear: left;}`

Comment: this gives me..

o
ooo
oo

instead of
ooo
ooo

Comment: this worked
.clear-row:nth-child(3n+2) {clear: left;}
any idea why it needs the +2? +1 didn't work.

Comment: Sorry didn't test it. It should actually be 3n+1. Inspect the markup maybe there's a stray div somewhere.

Comment: If you have a responsive grid you need to do different clears for every single breakpoint. A better answer would be not to use bootstrap grid but rather something that doesn't use floats.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try using `display:flex;` to add a uniform height to divs in a row as shown in this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/126437

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="article flex-col">
              content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="article flex-col">
              content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="article flex-col">
              content goes here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:0;
}

.row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
     margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}

.container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div,.row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
    width:100%;
}


.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Comment: this works too. Any advantage over Neps answer below? His sure means less code. ha.

Comment: For responsive web designs, flex is more cleaner and preferable than using `floats` and `clearfix`.

As mentioned here: http://imstillreallybored.com/2013/08/building-a-responsive-grid-with-css3-flexbox-and-no-floats/

"Flex allows for complex layouts and layouts containing many child elements to be much more lightweight and easier to code ( no need for extra jank and ugly clearflxes )"

Comment: Yes flexbox is good as long you don't need support for IE 9 and below

Comment: This seems to be overriding the use of bootstrap responsive column widths; I modified your markup example to include "col-lg-1" for large sizes, but this is being ignored now: http://www.bootply.com/coAnc0jJ8j.

Comment: Nice! Especially with dynamic content, when you want to show a variable  number of elements. Would upvote more if i could.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `min-height` to your column divs to maintain a uniformed layout like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="article">
    content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="article">
    content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="article">
    content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
    min-height: 200px; /* change to the height value of the longest column in the row */
}
```

Comment: tried that, but content (and heights) dynamically generate so can't set a min-height as i don't know what largest height will be.

Comment: No you add the background color to the `article` div **within** the column divs so they'll maintain the height of their content. The col divs min-height will just align the next row uniformly

Comment: see revised comment. can't set min-height as i don't know what it is.

Comment: If you look above in your visual example, the green area of say, box 1 can be the `article` div but the space below is from the col div with the min-height.

Comment: the boxes are an example. the divs are actually filled with real content. so i don't need the green to be full height - i need the container to all be the same height so they float every 3 columns like they should. the green is just to demonstrate some boxes.

Comment: @lowercase I have added a second answer highlighting a different approach of setting equal heights to the divs.

Answer (score 1):

Using [grid nesting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting):

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
    </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late but maybe someone's happy about this:

If all of your columns have the same width you can do the following:
(With this CSS you have to specify the size for all breakpoints)

```js
//Used to generate the html, not relevant to this question
for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
  jQuery(".row").append(
    '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">'+
    '<h1>Title '+i+'</h1>'+
    '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/'+getRandomInt(300, 700)+'/'+getRandomInt(200, 800)+'">'+
  '</div>');
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 544px) {
    .row.same-width .col-xs-1:nth-child(12n + 13), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xs-1:nth-child(12n + 13),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xs-1:nth-child(12n + 13) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n + 7), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n + 7),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n + 7) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n + 5), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n + 5),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n + 5) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n + 4), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n + 4),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n + 4) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n + 3), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n + 3),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n + 3) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xs-12:nth-child(1n + 2), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xs-12:nth-child(1n + 2),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xs-12:nth-child(1n + 2) {
        clear: left
    }
}

@media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row.same-width .col-sm-1:nth-child(12n + 13), html body > div.container ul.products .col-sm-1:nth-child(12n + 13),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-sm-1:nth-child(12n + 13) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n + 7), html body > div.container ul.products .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n + 7),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n + 7) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n + 5), html body > div.container ul.products .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n + 5),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n + 5) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n + 4), html body > div.container ul.products .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n + 4),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n + 4) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n + 3), html body > div.container ul.products .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n + 3),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n + 3) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-sm-12:nth-child(1n + 2), html body > div.container ul.products .col-sm-12:nth-child(1n + 2),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-sm-12:nth-child(1n + 2) {
        clear: left
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    .row.same-width .col-md-1:nth-child(12n + 13), html body > div.container ul.products .col-md-1:nth-child(12n + 13),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-md-1:nth-child(12n + 13) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-md-2:nth-child(6n + 7), html body > div.container ul.products .col-md-2:nth-child(6n + 7),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-md-2:nth-child(6n + 7) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-md-3:nth-child(4n + 5), html body > div.container ul.products .col-md-3:nth-child(4n + 5),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-md-3:nth-child(4n + 5) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-md-4:nth-child(3n + 4), html body > div.container ul.products .col-md-4:nth-child(3n + 4),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-md-4:nth-child(3n + 4) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-md-6:nth-child(2n + 3), html body > div.container ul.products .col-md-6:nth-child(2n + 3),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-md-6:nth-child(2n + 3) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-md-12:nth-child(1n + 2), html body > div.container ul.products .col-md-12:nth-child(1n + 2),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-md-12:nth-child(1n + 2) {
        clear: left
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .row.same-width .col-lg-1:nth-child(12n + 13), html body > div.container ul.products .col-lg-1:nth-child(12n + 13),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-lg-1:nth-child(12n + 13) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n + 7), html body > div.container ul.products .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n + 7),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n + 7) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n + 5), html body > div.container ul.products .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n + 5),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n + 5) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n + 4), html body > div.container ul.products .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n + 4),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n + 4) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n + 3), html body > div.container ul.products .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n + 3),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n + 3) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-lg-12:nth-child(1n + 2), html body > div.container ul.products .col-lg-12:nth-child(1n + 2),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-lg-12:nth-child(1n + 2) {
        clear: left
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .row.same-width .col-xl-1:nth-child(12n + 13), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xl-1:nth-child(12n + 13),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xl-1:nth-child(12n + 13) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xl-2:nth-child(6n + 7), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xl-2:nth-child(6n + 7),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xl-2:nth-child(6n + 7) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xl-3:nth-child(4n + 5), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xl-3:nth-child(4n + 5),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xl-3:nth-child(4n + 5) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xl-4:nth-child(3n + 4), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xl-4:nth-child(3n + 4),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xl-4:nth-child(3n + 4) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xl-6:nth-child(2n + 3), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xl-6:nth-child(2n + 3),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xl-6:nth-child(2n + 3) {
        clear: left
    }

    .row.same-width .col-xl-12:nth-child(1n + 2), html body > div.container ul.products .col-xl-12:nth-child(1n + 2),
    html body > div.container-fluid ul.products .col-xl-12:nth-child(1n + 2) {
        clear: left
    }
}

.row img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row same-width"></div>
```

If you're using SCSS the whole thing is a little bit cleaner:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 544px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

$grid-columns:               12 !default;

.row.same-width{
    $break-values: map-keys($grid-breakpoints);
    @each $breakpoint in $break-values{

        @if(index($break-values, $breakpoint) < length($break-values)){
            @media (min-width: #{map-get($grid-breakpoints, $breakpoint)}) and (max-width: #{map-get($grid-breakpoints, nth($break-values, index($break-values, $breakpoint)+1))}){
                @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
                    @if($grid-columns % $i == 0){
                        .col-#{$breakpoint}-#{$i}:nth-child(#{($grid-columns/$i)}n + #{($grid-columns/$i)+1}){
                            clear: left;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }@else{
            @media (min-width: #{map-get($grid-breakpoints, $breakpoint)}){
                @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
                    @if($grid-columns % $i == 0){
                        .col-#{$breakpoint}-#{$i}:nth-child(#{($grid-columns/$i)}n + #{($grid-columns/$i)+1}){  
                            clear: left;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```